# Python Error: request.exceptions.MissingsSchma error. trying to parse multiple urls and use requests module to access

Tags: python, web-scraping

From csv file, I am trying to parse urls and open them with requests module to get data. It parses
`https://` urls from column but whenever I try to access them through `request.get()`, it throws out
`requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'nan': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://nan?`  error.

function worked fine in jupyter notebook IDE, but when I copied and pasted the code to .py file. I have pipped necessary modules, and it parses correct urls.

This is part of code:

```
def compilationUpload(df):
    storelst = list(df['Store'])
    tag = list(df['Tag'].loc[df['Tag'].notna()])

    for (idx, items) in enumerate(storelst):
        print(idx, items)
        desc_data(items, df, idx)

def desc_data(url_str, df, idx):
    print(url_str)
    print(type(url_str))
    desc_page = requests.get(url_str) #this part encounters error
    desc_content = requests.get(url_str).text 

    if desc_page.status_code == 200:
```

Comment: When the program runs, what does it output for ```print(url_str)```?

Comment: You should check such errors with `print` gives you an exact picture of what the `request` is getting as an `url`

Comment: @DapperDuck, url string of website https://www.someurl.com

Comment: @AbhishekRai, will do!

Comment: @Linostrain please include your import statements

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from jsonfinder import jsonfinder
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import os
import shutil
import wget
import time
import urllib
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import glob`